# Finding a file with a file format

Tags: unix

I need to write a shell script to check if a file with specific file name format exists or not and if it exists need to archive. How can I look for that file. The format is totalload00n.txt. For eg totalload001.txt,totalload002.txt etc..Once I can find the latest file how can i extract the sequence number from the file and assign it to a variable.

Thanks

Comment: ls totalload00?.txt,  or find . -name 'totalload00?.txt'

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified the OS but for Linux you would write
find . -type f -name "*.txt"
then it would display all files with the extension ".txt".